# Why Calendar.setTimeZone() is not effecting on date which is retrieved from database

Tags: java, sql, date

I am saving date to database by setting GMT+5:30 timezone.
After getting same date from database, i am setting GMT+3:00 timezone.

But date is not changing....

For ex:

while inserting into database:

```
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.setTime(new Date());//some date 
  cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:30"));
  Date date = cal.getTime();
```

Ex: Now date is "Fri Nov 07 23:00:00 GMT 2014"

After retrieving from database:

```
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.setTime(retrievedDate);//retrievedDate is retrieved from database. here date is "Fri Nov 07 23:00:00 GMT 2014"
  cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+3:00"));
  Date date = cal.getTime();
```

Ex: Now also giving same date "Fri Nov 07 23:00:00 GMT 2014"

Answer (score 5):

Time, in this sense, is absolute. [It is just](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29)

> the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and
>   midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.

When you set the timezone with

```
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:30"));
```

you are simply changing a display property for the `Calendar`. Internally, it will still use the same millisecond value, but will display it differently +/- some hours/minutes.

When you eventually do

```
Date date = cal.getTime();
```

the `Date` object is created from that millisecond value, without knowledge of any time zone. Use a [`DateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) if you want to display it in the appropriate time zone.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the timezone won't change the calendar date.

If you are trying to output to a particular timezone format, use a DateFormat

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date = cal.getTime();
    System.out.println(date);
    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.FULL,DateFormat.FULL);
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+3:00"));
    System.out.println(df.format(date));
```

Answer (score 0):

Date is milliseconds holder, it cannot be changed with Calendar manipulation. Calendar may affect only textual representation of a date. Use SimpleDateFormatter to see date in a different timezones